# Spring Security - Why is SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returning AnonymousAuthenticationToken?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for a specific use case where I need to set the authentication object manually. When the user logs out, I retrieve the authentication object via SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() but it is returning AnonymousAuthenticationToken instead of the expected OAuth2Authentication?

```
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authoritiesMapper.mapAuthorities(user.getAuthorities()))

    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(attributes.getRequest()));

    OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(new CustomOAuth2Request(ImmutableMap.of(PARAM_SCOPE, SCOPE_OPENID), clientId,
            redirectUri, Sets.newHashSet(SCOPE_OPENID)), token);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(oAuth2Authentication);

    HttpSession session = attributes.getRequest().getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

And in my Logout code:

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Why is this not returning the Authentication that I am expecting?

Comment: How do you conclude that, what you get from getAuthentication method call is of type AnonymousAuthenticationToken? Did you try casting it to OAuth2Authentication? Do you get an error when you do so? Nice to share the OAuth2Authentication code as well.

Comment: Casting produces`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication.

[OAuth2Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2Authentication.html) is out of the box.